# Error when cloning git repository from a server on a local machine

Tags: git

I installed git on a remote server that I have hosted, I would like it to be my git server and be collaborated by the developers.
But when I try to clone my repository that is on the server on my machine to start collaborating I get the following error:

and my server currently has no proxy and firewall enabled

````
git clone https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/home/processador/Download/moveis.git
Cloning into 'moveis'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/home/processador/Download/moveis.git/':
Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx port 443: Connection refused```
````

Comment: Check that the service is running on that host on that port (or a firewall is in the middle refusing that traffic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Git does not mean an HTTPS server is automatically listening for your request.

You could, however, have a running sshd (SSH daemon), which means you could try an SSH URL, provided you have deployed a public key to the right remote account `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: If using SSH, there's no requirement to have the certificates set up.... that certainly makes it simpler than having to provide credentials every time you do fetch/pull/push.